# Why do I get “undefined” in the table in my Firebase app?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an app that retrieves data from Firebase and show it in a table using JavaScript. The problem is that it’s showing me “undefined” in the app and in the console and when I try to print the values directly from the functions they contain a value, so can anyone please help me with this?

This is my code:

```
function doSomething() {
  var something = firebase.database().ref('*****');

  //comment selection 
  something.on('value', function gotData(data) {
    var values = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(values);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < keys.length) {
      var k = keys[i];
      var comments = values[k].comment;
      var idU = values[k].id;
      var idS = values[k].idservice;
      var nom = getuser(idU);
      var service = getservice(idS);
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      var td2 = document.createElement('td');
      var td3 = document.createElement('td');
      var t = document.createTextNode(i + ':' + comments);
      var t2 = document.createTextNode(nom);
      var t3 = document.createTextNode(service);

      td.appendChild(t);
      td2.appendChild(t2);
      td3.appendChild(t3);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tr.appendChild(td3);
      document.getElementById("commentsection").appendChild(tr);
      i++;
    }
  }, errData);
}

function getuser(IdU) {
  var users = firebase.database().ref('******');
  users.on('value', function getData(data) {
    var values = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(values);
    var j = 0;

    while (j < keys.length) {
      var k = keys[j];

      if (k === IdU) {
        var name = values[k].nom;

        console.log(name);

        return name;

        break;
      } else {
        console.log('not found');

        break;
      }
      j++;
    }
  }, errData);
}

function getservice(IdS) {
  var service = firebase.database().ref('******');
  service.on('value', function getData(data) {
    var values = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(values);
    var s = 0;

    while (s < keys.length) {
      var k = keys[s];

      if (k === IdS) {
        var nomservice = values[k].nomservice

        console.log(nomservice);

        return nomservice;

        break;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
      s++;
    }
  }, errData);
}

function errData(err) {
  console.log('error!');
  console.log(err);
}
```

This is a screenshot for what I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In `getservice` the `while` loop will at most run once and `s++` will never be reached due to both possible conditions `return`ing.

Comment: thank you so much for answering fast , but can you please explain more I didn't get your point.

Comment: A `return` causes a function to exit. So in which case will `s++` be reached?

Comment: oh I see, I changed the 'return' position  to the end of the function , but this time I get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: nomservice is not defined"